# python range occurrence in other range

Tags: python

How can I do something like this:

```
>>> xrange(4, 10) in xrange(3, 20)
TRUE
```

Comment: In relation to this, how do `xrange()` objects compare? I mean you can try `xrange(4, 10) < xrange(3, 20)` and you get some result. Is it something meaningful? A sequence comparison or by address/hash?!

Comment: Also, what about case with reversed ranges - is `xrange(9, 3, -1) in xrange(3, 20)`? Do both ranges have to be inverted or just fit as sets? What if there are gaps in one of the ranges (step was used)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `(min1 >= min2) and (max1 <= max2)` ?

(Assuming `min1, max1 = 4, 10` and `min2, max2 = 3, 20`)

Note: You want to compare endpoints *without* actually making / evaluating the ranges, otherwise it'll be horribly inefficient.

*edit:* This also works; not better, but prettier imo: `min2 <= min1 <= max1 <= max2`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `min2 <= min1 <= max1 <= max2`?

Comment: @jellybean - depends on whether you want "strict" sub-ranges or not; but I suppose that's better as a default option. Changed.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for one set being contained in another set, try:

```
>>> set(xrange(4, 10)).issubset(set(range(3,20))
```

If you're looking to compare endpoints since you'll always use ranges for this, than you can just compare the endpoints like @zoli2k.

[EDIT] An edit was requested.

Comment: Why on earth did I get downvoted?  At least leave an obnoxious comment behind!

Comment: First I thought the use of `set()` is inefficient but now I realize this is the only solution that works correct with ranges with step!=1, e.g. `range(1,30,3)` or `range(30,1,-1)`. ++

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>>min(xrange(4, 10)) > min(range(3, 20)) and max(xrange(4, 10)) < max(range(3, 20))
 True
```

Comment: Using `min` and `max` on an `xrange` is inefficient. Use `[0]` and `[-1]` instead.

Comment: @jleedev: clever note but what if one of the ranges is inverted, that is, a negative number was used as step? ;-)

Comment: @Nas Banov: Good point.  You should use min of [0] and [-1] and max of [0] and [1].  How meta.

Answer (score 0):

Given two ranges, you can do this:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> b = range(5,15)
>>> c = range(15,25)
>>> any(x in a for x in b)
True
>>> any(x in a for x in c)
False
```

This is slightly inefficient, and if have very large (100+ elements) ranges to inspect, it is better for the type of `a` to be 'set' instead of list. i.e.:

```
>>> a = set(range(10))
```

Sets don't have order, but the `in` operator is much faster.